# JavaScript match returns matches plus empty strings

Tags: javascript, regex

Seems like a bit of a dumb question but looking over all the MDN documentation I cannot tell why this is happening.

My match returns not only the words in a sentence but also empty strings, one of each match it appears.

```
var input = "This is a something";
input.match(/[a-z0-9]*/gi); # ["This", "", "is", "", "a", "", "something", ""]
```

It happens even for a single word.

```
var input = "This";
input.match(/[a-z0-9]*/gi); # ["This", ""]
```

I have also tried adding a word boundary (\b) but it does not help at all. Can anybody tell me what is going on here? I just want to match all the words out of a sentence.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Look up regex `*`. It means "0 or more". Then contrast with `+`.

Comment: Ughhhh, good point. I thought * was equal to {1,}. Anyways changed * to {1,} and it works as expected.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @recneps You can use `+` for `{1,}`

Comment: @soktinpk nice! you just learn something new everyday don't you.

Comment: @recneps - you should checkout regex101.com, and make sure to click on the javascript tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the +, but for your use case (matching all words in a sentence), you might be better off using split.

```
var input = "This is a something";
input.split(' '); // ["This", "is", "a", "something"]
```

And in this case, it looks like split is what you're looking for too:

```
input = "words with a-hyphen";
input.split(' '); // ["words", "with", "a-hyphen"]
input.match(/[a-z0-9]+/gi); //["words", "with", "a", "hyphen"]
```

You can always use a match on it later if needed

Comment: Yeah, good thought, split would be more straight forward. But I also need to split on special characters (eg "something\nelse") and punctuation (eg :) should not be considered a word.

Comment: @recneps You can also use a regex on `split`. `"This is\na: something".split(/\s|\n/);`

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "why" question, if you have a quantifier that allows an empty match, like `*` or `?`, and there are no matching characters in the current position, regex considers an empty string to be a valid match, pushes it into the array of matches and continues from the next position. For example,

```
"a b".match(/\w*/g)
```

which returns

```
["a", "", "b", ""]
```

Here, `"a"` matches at the pos 0, `""` at the pos 1 etc (remember, regex "position" is between the characters, just like the standard text cursor).

Another, rather pathological, example of this behaviour would be

```
"abc".match(/\W?/g)
```

which returns three empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using your own regex:

```
var input = "This is a something";
input.match(/[a-z0-9]*/gi); # ["This", "", "is", "", "a", "", "something", ""]
```

You should change the `*` quantifier to `+`

```
var input = "This is a something";
input.match(/[a-z0-9]+/gi); ==> will generate # ["This", "is", "a", "something"]
```